# How does weight factor into legal allowance in Germany?

Tags: regulations, weight, germany

I'm in Germany and I want to buy a drone. Are there any weight-dependent flight restrictions?

Comment: While I know that 'it is easy to Google this' isn't a very valid close-reason (because one aim of an SE site can be to become to top Google result for other Googlers), I do think questions should show some research effort, and not just put all of that in a self-answer. That makes this question lack detail or clarity to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's quite a good summary of the rules on the website of the federal transport department (BMVI):

https://www.bmvi.de/SharedDocs/DE/Publikationen/LF/flyer-die-neue-drohnen-verordnung.pdf?__blob=publicationFile

It appears, that there are these restrictions:

- **For everything < 250g** no additional restrictions apply. It's still not allowed to fly at certain places (parliament, airports, ...) and you must stay below 100 m and you must always be able to see the drone.
- **For everything > 250g** you need to label your drone with your name and address
- **For everything > 2kg** you need to participate in some governmental training and have a proof of ability
- **For everything > 5kg** you need special permission from the state aviation department (Landesluftfahrtbehörde).